# Java - How to close Kafka consumer when no more data is available

Tags: java, kafka-consumer-api

I'm using apache-kafka 2.11-0.10.0 to do data transmission.

If the producer get something wrong and break down, the consumer will keep polling the message but get nothing.

I want to know how to close the consumer when there is no more data available.

In Kafka 0.7.0 and 0.8.0, I see `consumer.timeout.ms` which will throw a timeout exception to the consumer if no message is available for consumption after the specified interval.

But in my newer version, I don't see such config in `ConsumerConfig`. Can somebody help me?

By the way, is there any method to get the end offset of specific topic partition. In version 2.11, there is `KafkaConsumer.endOffsets`. In my version I don't see it, too.